# Ansible aws_ec2 inventory plugin did not pass its verify_file() method

Tags: python-2.7, ansible, ansible-inventory

unfortunately our aws_ec2 inventory plugin does not work anymore and I cant figure it our why.

It worked the last days but after an update on the ansible VM it shows only the same error.

Error:

```
/opt/ansible/bin/ansible-inventory -i inventory/ec2.aws.yml --graph -vvvvvv
ansible-inventory 2.9.2
  config file = /home/XXXXX/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/XXXXX/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /opt/ansible/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /opt/ansible/bin/ansible-inventory
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Jun 28 2022, 15:30:04) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]
Using /home/XXXXX/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
ansible_collections.amazon.aws.plugins.inventory.aws_ec2 declined parsing /home/XXXXX/ansible/XXXXX/ec2.aws.yml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
```

I already checked if boto3 and botocore are installed, and they are for the python2.7 version that Ansible uses:

```
python2.7 -m pip freeze

boto3==1.26.69
botocore==1.29.69
```

This is the inventory yaml file:

```
plugin: amazon.aws.aws_ec2
cache: yes
cache_timeout: 600
regions:
  - eu-central-1
validate_certs: False

keyed_groups: 
  - prefix: os
    key: tags['OS']

hostnames: 
  - tag:Name

compose:
  ansible_host: private_ip_address
```

I am using this in the "/home/XXXXX/ansible/ansible.cfg":

```
[inventory]
enable_plugins = vmware_vm_inventory, amazon.aws.aws_ec2
```

Also the amazon.aws collection is installed:

```
/opt/ansible/bin/ansible-galaxy collection install amazon.aws
Process install dependency map
Starting collection install process
Skipping 'amazon.aws' as it is already installed
```

Also the credentials are exported as env vars:

```
env
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXXXXX
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXXXXXXX
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=XXXXXXXXXX
```

Does anyone have an idea what's the issue?

I was trying to run a playbook and every time the same issue comes up.

`ansible_collections.amazon.aws.plugins.inventory.aws_ec2 declined parsing /home/XX/ansible/XX/ec2.aws.yml as it did not pass its verify_file() method`

Comment: It appears that the "update on the ansible VM" was you changing the name of the inventory file, because that's not a filename that has ever been accepted by this plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ec2.aws.yml` has never been a valid filename for use with the `aws_ec2` inventory plugin.

Inventory files for this plugin must end in either `aws_ec2.yml` or `aws_ec2.yaml`.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes its the obvious things.